# True/false test about $|\cdot|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

Let $a, b>0$ be fixed and let $f$ be a continuous function. As an exercise for my math class, I have this true/false test. I would kindly ask if you can tell me if my answers are correct or not (these $2$ are the most difficult questions for me).

1. If $f<0$, then $\int_0^a f dx = -\int_0^a |f| dx;\qquad$ (about me this is True)
2. If $f<0$, thus
   $$\left(-\int_0^a f dx+ b>0\right) \implies \left(-\int_0^a |f| dx< b\right).$$

About me, also 2. is correct. I would justify it in this way:
$$ \int_0^a |f| dx +b>-\int_0^a f dx+ b>0 \text{ and then } -\int_0^a |f| dx< b.$$

Could someone please tell me if my answers are correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

if $f<0$, then $f=-|f|$, hence

$$\int_0^a f\, dx =\int_0^a -|f|\, dx =-\int_0^af\, dx$$

For the second part,

$$\int_0^a|f|\,dx+b\color{red}=-\int_0^af\, dx + b>0$$

Hence we have $$b>-\int_0^a|f|\,dx.$$